# getting error while importing cv2 module in ubuntu amazon instance

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, opencv, python

getting error while doing this

```
import cv2
```

```
python3: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)



import cv2
python3: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: How did you install opencv?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps CUDA was not installed properly
check it